# CSS rules for fixing header, footer, and center-image

Tags: html, css

I have three images: one.png, two.png, and three.png. Using CSS, how would I fix one.png to the top-center of the page, three.png to the bottom-center of the page, and two.png to the middle of the page? two.png should be vertically- and horizontally-aligned the entire setup should be consistent when the viewport is resized. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi there! This is a topic that's covered many, many places. You can find answers with some very quick Googling. Just look up "css absolute positioning" and maybe "css vertical align".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the top and bottom images, you'll want to position:absolute; and add either top:0px or bottom:0px;

The middle one, you'll also want to add position:absolute;. In this case, there's a few other CSS tricks that will help center this vertically.

```
img.two {
  top: 50%;
  height:100px;
  margin-top: -50px; /* Half the height */
}
```

See my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9GFu9/2/